# Have I parsed this correctly? 在这一重大的历史时点，和讯网对著名经济学家张维迎就改革的发展问题进行了一次非常深入的访谈。

Tags: translation

> 在这一重大的历史时点，
>
> 和讯网
>
> 对
>
> 著名经济学家张维迎就改革的
>
> 发展问题
>
> 进行了
>
> 一次非常深入的访谈。

(From [CaiJing.com.cn](http://economy.caijing.com.cn/2013-11-07/113534884.html); link now broken.)

> At this important historical point, Hexun.com has conducted a very in-depth discussion on the question of development, which renowned economics professor, ZHANG Weiyin, has reformed.

Have I parsed and translated this sentence correctly? Or is there some better interpretation I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`在这一重大的历史时点，和讯网/对(著名经济学家)张维迎(就改革的发展问题)进行了(一次非常深入的)访谈。`

the main structure is `和讯网对张维迎进行了访谈`

So the correct translation that reflects this structure should be

`At this important historical point, Hexun.com has conducted a very in-depth discussion (or interview) with the renowned economist ZHANG Weiyin on the question (or problem) of future directions of reform.`

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, what I'm looking at is the structure:
A interviews B on C
and in Chinese it is ordered like this
A dui B C jinxing fangtan.
Is this correct?

Comment: @lan No, you missed the corresponding "on C" structure in Chinese, it should be "A 对 B **就 C** 进行 访谈".

Comment: So this is a new meaning for 就 for me. Is it more or less synonymous with 关于? Or is it restricted to this sort of construction?

Comment: 就 can be used as a proposition meaning on/at/about. `就字面上看` means `according to the literal meaning`, `就这件事而言` means `speaking of this matter per se`

Comment: 就 for me is more like 'in terms of...', 'regarding...', 'on...' or 'with respect to...'.

Answer (score -2):

Using 时刻 instead of 时点 will be better.

在这一重大的历史时刻，

和讯网

对著名经济学家张维迎

就改革的发展问题

进行了一次非常深入的访谈。